# OWC gives error on publish website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have develop web App. I do not have office on server and want to deploy my publish folder over there.

Is Microsoft office is madatory for OWC?
If yes is there any way we can use it without excel installed?

```
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using OWC11;

namespace AspNetResources.Owc
{
    public partial class _default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
                BuildCharts ();
        }

        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        private void BuildCharts ()
        {
            string[] chartCategoriesArr = new string [] {"Accord Coupe", "Accord Sedan", "Civic Coupe", "Civic Sedan", "Civic Si"};
            string[] chartValuesArr = new string []{"19400", "15900", "13710", "13010", "19070"};

            string chartCategoriesStr = String.Join ("\t", chartCategoriesArr);
            string chartValuesStr = String.Join ("\t", chartValuesArr);

            OWC11.ChartSpaceClass       oChartSpace = new OWC11.ChartSpaceClass ();
            OWC11.ChartChartTypeEnum    chartType;

            /*--------------------------------------------------------------
             * Try using different char types just for fun
             * -------------------------------------------------------------
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeArea;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeArea3D;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeBarClustered;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeBar3D;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeColumnClustered;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeColumn3D;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeDoughnut;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeLineStacked;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeLine3D;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeLineMarkers;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypePie;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypePie3D;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeRadarSmoothLine;
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeSmoothLine;
            */

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Give pie and doughnut charts a legend on the bottom. For the rest of
            // them let the control figure it out on its own.
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            chartType = ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeColumn3D;

            if (chartType == ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypePie ||
                chartType == ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypePie3D ||
                chartType == ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeDoughnut)
            {
                oChartSpace.HasChartSpaceLegend = true;
                oChartSpace.ChartSpaceLegend.Position = ChartLegendPositionEnum.chLegendPositionBottom;
            }

            oChartSpace.Border.Color = "white";
            oChartSpace.Charts.Add(0);
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].HasTitle = true;
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].Type = chartType;
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].ChartDepth = 125;
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].AspectRatio = 80;
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].Title.Caption = "Pricing Of 2004 Hondas";
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].Title.Font.Bold = true;

            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection.Add(0);
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection.Add ();

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // If you're charting a pie or a variation thereof percentages make a lot
            // more sense than values...
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (chartType == ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypePie ||
                chartType == ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypePie3D ||
                chartType == ChartChartTypeEnum.chChartTypeDoughnut)
            {
                oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection[0].HasPercentage = true;
                oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection[0].HasValue = false;
            }
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Not so for other chart types where values have more meaning than
            // percentages.
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            else
            {
                oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection[0].HasPercentage = false;
                oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection[0].HasValue = true;
            }

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Plug your own visual bells and whistles here
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].Caption = String.Empty;
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection[0].Font.Name = "verdana";
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection[0].Font.Size = 10;
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection[0].Font.Bold = true;
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection[0].Font.Color = "white";
            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].DataLabelsCollection[0].Position = ChartDataLabelPositionEnum.chLabelPositionCenter;

            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].SetData (OWC11.ChartDimensionsEnum.chDimCategories,
                Convert.ToInt32(OWC11.ChartSpecialDataSourcesEnum.chDataLiteral), chartCategoriesStr);

            oChartSpace.Charts[0].SeriesCollection[0].SetData (OWC11.ChartDimensionsEnum.chDimValues,
                Convert.ToInt32(OWC11.ChartSpecialDataSourcesEnum.chDataLiteral), chartValuesStr);

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Pick your favorite image format
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            byte[]  byteArr = (byte[]) oChartSpace.GetPicture ("png", 500, 500);

            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Store the chart image in Session to be picked up by an HttpHandler later
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            HttpContext     ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            string          chartID = Guid.NewGuid ().ToString ();

            ctx.Session [chartID] = byteArr;
            imgHondaLineup.ImageUrl = string.Concat ("chart.ashx?", chartID);
        }

        #region Web Form Designer generated code
        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {    

        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

It gives error that

```
Server Error in '/owc' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'owc' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message means that the file `owc.dll` or one of it's references is missing.

Check whether the file is either:

- in the `bin` folder of your web project (after publishing);
- in the GAC (C:\windows\assembly).

If it does exist there, you can use Reflector, or similar products to see what the references of `owc.dll` are and you have to check those references too.